# red underline error in MainActivity on AppCompatActivity

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I updated my IDE yesterday and when am opening new project, i found red underline error in MainActivity on AppCompatActivity

[image: the word AppCompatActivity is underlined with red error]

Comment: Without error messages, it is not possible to say more than "invalidate and restart your android studio". Be sure that you are adding all the details you have to have meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the grayed-out line with the following line.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```